# package-info.class content in jaxb context

Tags: java, jaxb

Heyho,

i'm currently having problems with the JAXB serialization process.
jaxb version 2, used for serialization properties.

Is it possible to add multiple package level annotations in "package-info.class"? Currently i'm creating this file manually, there's already one "adapter entry" in it and it has to stay there. Although i'm searching like an idiot, every example is with just *one* entry, but i guess that's just not possible, because the semantic should be more flexible, allowing multiple package level annotations than just one.

The problem is, that i'm using a @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(AdapterForMap.class) on every map-member in a class, but the map actually contains another type (as value), let's say Font, which needs to have a appropriate xml adapter. At the moment i'm not able to use this Font-Adapter-like, because 'package-info.class' already has one entry.

thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Did you try @XmlJavaTypeAdapters? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapters.html

Comment: Yeah. I'm currently using Blaise Doughan's approach to specify several adapter in the package-info.class, this works fine now. A problem occurs when i have a complex structure like Map<Integer, Font/RGB).. although i'm providing an adapter (and "registered" it in the package-info.class) exception are thrown. Sometimes it's the message, that "org.eclipse.swt.graphics.RGB does not have a no-arg default constructor.", sometimes it's the famous "not defined in this context" error message. i found similar problems with nested complex constructs, but there seems to be no general best practice. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `@XmlJavaTypeAdapters` can be used at the package level to register many instances of `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter`.

**package-info**

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=DateTime.class, value=DateTimeAdapter.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=DateMidnight.class, value=DateMidnightAdapter.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=LocalDate.class, value=LocalDateAdapter.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=LocalTime.class, value=LocalTimeAdapter.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type=LocalDateTime.class, value=LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
})
package blog.jodatime;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters;    
import org.joda.time.*;
```

**For a Complete Example**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/jaxb-and-joda-time-dates-and-times.html

Comment: Yeah great, thanks, that's just what i've needed, although i already read this example you linked.. obviously i was just too stupid to extract the important part at the end of the article ;-/